# Launching python virtualenv code outside of Visual Studio

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a Python code in Visual Studio which reads input, opens a file based on it, then makes a pyplot based on the file and saves the plot. All files are in the same folder as the .sln file.

To use the matplotlib package, I have used virtual environment. That led to creating "env" folder, but I can not find my application there.

So I would like to know a way how can I launch the code via doubleclicking a .py application, instead of launching Visual Studio and pressing Ctrl+F5 every time. Simply copying the code into "mycode.py" obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate the virtualenv in order to execute your Python code inside your virtual environment.

To activate the virtual environment you have to type the following in the terminal:

On macOS and Linux:

```
source env/bin/activate
```

On Windows:

```
.\env\Scripts\activate
```

---

You can confirm you’re in the virtual environment by checking the location of your Python interpreter, it should point to the env directory.

On macOS and Linux:

```
which python
.../env/bin/python
```

On Windows:

```
where python
.../env/bin/python.exe
```

---

To execute your python file just type `python myfile.py` in the terminal instead of double-clicking it.

Comment: So creating a .bat file which will execute these steps (on Windows cmd) will be a way to launch the script with one-click?

Comment: This should be possible, the .bat file should first activate the virtualenv and then execute the python file.

Comment: Yeah I have got around some technical issues and now the bat file actually opens cmd and works as intended. Thanks!